# String Find() for findng small differences

Tags: c++, string, find

I have some SKUs that i need to differenciate by a letter number code such as D2 D3 D4 etc

im using a simple if(lineVector[1].find("D2"))

but when i do this with the multiple statements it seems to fall into the first if and never change.  My question is whether find is seeing the D and deciding it doesnt need to look past that because its found it.

any suggestions

heres my code in short

```
if (lineVector[7].find("D2"))
            {
                tempQuantity = 2;
                totalQuantity += tempQuantity;
            }

            else if (lineVector[7].find("D3"))
            {
                tempQuantity = 3;
                totalQuantity += tempQuantity;
            }

            else if (lineVector[7].find("D4"))
            {
                tempQuantity = 4;
                totalQuantity += tempQuantity;
            }

            else if (lineVector[7].find("D5"))
            {
                tempQuantity = 5;
                totalQuantity += tempQuantity;
            }
            else
            {
                tempQuantity = 1;
                totalQuantity += tempQuantity;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// string::find
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  std::string str ("There are two needles in this haystack with needles.");
  std::string str2 ("needle");

  // different member versions of find in the same order as above:
  std::size_t found = str.find(str2);
  if (found!=std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "first 'needle' found at: " << found << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The find function return the index where the match occur on success.On failure (not found) it returns std::string::npos and its value is not zero.

So you have to compare the return value with std::string::npos.

I suggest you if you have unique skus use set(if sorting order required) or unordered_set(order doesnt matter).